# Test ADF Claim Store in Java?

Tags: ambient-data-framework

I'd like my team to make/use a Java equivalent to the [Tridion Cookbook's Ambient Data Framework Test page](https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/tree/master/AmbientDataFramework), some nice functonality from Peter Kjaer.

- Does anyone know if there is a *Java* version available?
- If not, do we just need to change the references and replace ASP.NET controls with the matching tags? Would the JavaScript be roughly the same?

**Edit**: pointed link to Github instead of Google Code.

Comment: A JSP version has been on my TODO list for ages (not enough time!). I've got one that's a work in progress that I can try to find if nobody else has one.

Comment: That'd be great. I don't necessarily need all the claims, just enough to point the devs in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a JSP version available on the *tridion-practice* GitHub repository:
https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/blob/master/AmbientDataFramework/ClaimStore.jsp

Unless you are planning to use it without an internet connection, you only need to download the JSP file and the json-smart library it depends on. The rest of the files are loaded from CDNs.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I shared this with the devs on my project. I'll ask they consider sharing any updates they do with this.

Comment: Sounds good. I've since converted the ASP.NET version to use knockout (with the javascript and CSS hosted on GitHub Pages) with the plan to create a JSP version as well. That way they will both have the same features and look - with the only difference being how they create the source JSON with the ADF claims. Stay tuned :)

Comment: Updated my answer as the new Knockout versions are now on GitHub.